# Creating a Terminal Program with Python

Tags: python, command-line

I recently started learning python. I have created some basic webapps with Django and wrote some simple scripts. After using VIM as a Python IDE I really fell I love with "Terminal programs" (is there an official term for this?). Right now I am capable of doing simple things like asking someones age and printing it to the screen. However this comes down to running a .py script and after this script is done the normal bash return. I would like create a program that I can run from the command line and that would allow the same user experience as VIM (one that you open and close). For example I created a simple script to import RSS feeds. It would be cool if I could open my terminal type the name of my program -> program would open -> Then I would like to use commands like :findsomething. Basically have real interaction with my program.

To conclude:

- How would I go about creating such a program?
- What kinds of modules, books or site would you recommend

Comment: What you're describing is a terminal application, not a command line program

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A true command-line program is something in the vein of `ls` or `grep`; it is started from the command-line, but it's non-interactive and can be used in pipelines and combined with other programs. A typical command-line program has no interactive user experience, instead relying on shell's history and init file for customization.

What you want to create is a *curses* application, that uses the full capabilities of the TTY as an interactive platform, for better or worse. To do that, look up [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html).

Comment: Thanks I started learning the curses module. Seems be exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 31):

On a *nix system (linux/unix), 
if you:

```
$ chmod 0744 your_file.py

-rwxr--r--   your_file.py
```

and add the path to python as the first line of `your_file.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or (in my case):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

Once you do that, instead of running it like this:

```
$ python your_file.py
```

You can run it like this:

```
$ ./your_file.py
```

or even rename it to `yourfile` and run it like this:

```
$ ./yourfile
```

and if you then copy `yourfile` to your bin (i.e. `#!/usr/bin/`, or `#!/usr/local/bin/`)
you can run it like this:

```
$ yourfile
```

Then you can...

Use `raw_input()` to solicit and get input from you user.

`your_file.py`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import os

while(True):
    # cntrl-c to quit
    input = raw_input('your_prompt$ ')
    input = input.split()
    if input[0] == 'ls':
        dire = '.'
        if len(input) > 1:
            dire = input[1]
        print('\n'.join(os.listdir(dire)))
    else:
        print('error')
```

`your_file.py` use example:

```
$ chmod 744 your_file.py 
$ cp your_file.py /usr/local/bin/your_file 
$ your_file 
your_prompt$ ls
list_argv.py
your_file.py
your_ls.py
your_subprocess.py
your_prompt$ ls .
list_argv.py
your_file.py
your_ls.py
your_subprocess.py
your_prompt$ pwd
error
your_prompt$ ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/your_file", line 7, in <module>
    input = raw_input('your_prompt$ ')
KeyboardInterrupt
$
```

Grab arguments with `sys.argv` from the command line when you run your script:

`list_argv.py`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

`list_argv.py` use example:

```
$ python list_argv.py 
['list_argv.py']
$ python list_argv.py hello
['list_argv.py', 'hello']
$ python list_argv.py hey yo
['list_argv.py', 'hey', 'yo']

$ chmod 744 list_argv.py 
$ ./list_argv.py 
['./list_argv.py']
$ ./list_argv.py hi
['./list_argv.py', 'hi']
$ ./list_argv.py hey yo
['./list_argv.py', 'hey', 'yo']

$ cp list_argv.py /usr/local/bin/list_argv
$ list_argv hey yo
['/usr/local/bin/list_argv', 'hey', 'yo']
```

Replace `raw_input()` with `sys.argv`.

'your_ls.py':

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import sys
import os

dire = '.'
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    dire = sys.argv[1]
print('\n'.join(os.listdir(dire)))
```

'your_ls.py' use example:

```
$ chmod 744 your_ls.py 
$ cp your_ls.py /usr/local/bin/your_ls
$ your_ls 
list_argv.py
your_file.py
your_ls.py
your_subprocess.py
$ your_ls .
list_argv.py
your_file.py
your_ls.py
your_subprocess.py
$ your_ls blah
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/your_ls", line 9, in <module>
    print('\n'.join(os.listdir(dire)))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'blah'
```

Use `subprocess.Popen` to access anything you could from the command line.

`your_subprocess.py`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import os
import subprocess

while(True):
    # cntrl-c to quit
    input = raw_input('your_prompt$ ')

    process = subprocess.Popen(input, shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    out, err = process.communicate()

    print(out)
    print(err)
```

`your_subprocess.py` use example:

```
$ chmod 744 your_subprocess.py 
$ cp your_subprocess.py /usr/local/bin/your_subprocess
$ your_subprocess 
your_prompt$ ls
list_argv.py
your_file.py
your_ls.py
your_subprocess.py


your_prompt$ ls .
list_argv.py
your_file.py
your_ls.py
your_subprocess.py


your_prompt$ pwd
/Users/ox/_workspace/cmd_ln


your_prompt$ blah

/bin/sh: blah: command not found

your_prompt$ ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/your_subprocess", line 8, in <module>
    input = raw_input('your_prompt$ ')
KeyboardInterrupt
$
```

BREAK STUFF!

:-D

HAVE FUN!

-ox

Comment: Thanks!! Your answer is super useful. Do you know how to install python command line app by pip or brew?

Comment: `sudo pip install ipython`
hold the `sudo` if you are in a python virtual environment and 
checkout ipython notebook: 
`pip install ipython[notebook]`
it is so freaking cool!

Comment: Thank you, super useful and instructions full!

Answer (score 10):

You should take a look at the [cmd](http://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) module.

See the [Python Cookbook](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/tags/meta%3arequires=cmd/) for examples of its use.

Answer (score 4):

THe simplest way to do an interactive console application would be:

```
while True:
    command = raw_input('command? ').strip()
    if command == 'say_hello':
        print('Hello')
    elif command == 'other_thing':
        print('Doing something else')
    elif command == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid Command.')
```

That's the basic structure. If you want something more vim-like, you'll probably need to use the curses library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an standalone binary for a UNIX system, use [`freeze`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze).  If you want one for a Windows system, look into [`py2exe`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Py2Exe).  To control locations of output on your screen, use the [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) module.